# Handling 10000 threads using Executor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a web service which is continuously accessed by more than 20 servers which are sending data. I have used activeMQ where data is queued for some time and than using async task this data is dequed.

My async task thread class is shown below.

```
public class myConsumer {

    public void  asyncConsumer() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        final MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver(); 

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        try{
             Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     receiver.receiveMessage();          
                 }
           }); 

         executorService.shutdown();
         executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("tasks interrupted");
        }finally {
            if (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
                logger.error("cancel non-finished tasks");
            }
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

I have 10000 of threads running. My applcation server is stopped due to unusual behavior. How to handle this many no of thread using above code.

Comment: On Windows, 10000 threads is quite much. Try [Testlimit -t -n](https://live.sysinternals.com/WindowsInternals/)

Comment: Why are you steadily creating excutors instead of reusing a single one that has load management and is able to start and stop threads as required?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a thread pool executor rather than single thread executor, and make sure it's only one instance of the thread pool receiving messages. This way you can keep track of and limit the amount of concurrent threads.

Here's an example of how it can be done. By having the executorservice static you assure that it's only one instance, and it's limited to max 10 simultaneous threads. When you call asyncConsumer to process a received message a MyReceiver  (which I assume is going to process the message) is created and invoked inside the thread pool.

```
public class MyConsumer {

    static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public void  asyncConsumer() {          
        Future future = executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               new MyReceiver().receiveMessage();          
            }
        });                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Added an example - does it make sense to you?